# Can't installing R packages on linux mint 15 32bits

Tags: linux

I'm trying to install de ggplot library so I use this command

```
 install.packages('ggplot2', dependencies = TRUE)
```

When I write library(ggplot2) nothing happens there isn't an error message so I supouse that  the installation process work, but when I try to use the gplot function I get this:

```
 Error: could not find function "gplot"
```

I try to open R Studio as super user and install again, and also try to install the library from the tar.gz package but all the time I get the exact same error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Actually the Function is "qplot" not gplot.

For reference visit:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/ggplot2.pdf

Then go to Page No. 145 and check out for qplot (Quick plot):

Usage:

```
qplot(x, y = NULL, ..., data, facets = NULL, margins = FALSE,
geom = "auto", xlim = c(NA, NA), ylim = c(NA, NA), log = "",
main = NULL, xlab = deparse(substitute(x)),
ylab = deparse(substitute(y)), asp = NA, stat = NULL, position = NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you might try "ggplot()" rather than "gplot()"

Comment: I try that to, but the function is gplot, any way its now Solved, apparently I have to restart the program after install the tar.gz packages